# Caprica jquery orgchart tiers levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, orgchart

I'm using https://github.com/caprica/jquery-orgchart in my site.  For normal org structure it works great.  I've been asked to show a top level person, then, on the next, line 2 higher level people, then on the last 2 people on a third row.

Picture a VP(Top), 2 directors(row 2), and 2 managers(row 3).

Data:

```html
<ul id="organisation" class="hide">
    <li>Name Top Row
        <ul>
            <li>Goes onto Row 2</li>
            <li>Goes onto Row 2</li>
            <li>Goes onto Row 3</li>
            <li>Goes onto Row 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

For the life of me I can't get this working.  Does anyone have a code example URL or a jsfiddle that does this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the row 3 managers under one of the row 2 directors or are all of the managers under the VP?

Comment: VP(Top)
Next row 2 directors(row 2) with lines going to VP
Next row 2 managers(row 3) with lines going to VP

Comment: Hmm, yeah that's not a typical hierarchy, I'll look at it again later when I get off